# Get data from two tables using foreign key in Django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a vendor table it has following structure:

```
id  vendor_name
```

I have another table named purchases that have the following structure:

```
id  product_id   us er_id   vendor_id
```

Then, there is auth_user table by default that has users email address, first_name, last_name etc.

I need to create an API in django class based so that I can get users email address, first_name, last_name etc. based on vendor_id column that is in purchase table when I use GET /vendor/{vendor_id}

Note: I need this API to be created in class based model and views:

My code:

model.py

```
class Vendor(models.Models):
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('vendor_name',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vendor_name

class Purchases(models.Models):
    user = models.OneToOneFiled(User, on_delete=models.CASECADE)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey('Vendor', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vendor_id
```

views.py

```
class VendorDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestoryAPIView):
    queryset= Vendor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VendorSerializer
    name = 'vendor-details'
```

I want JSON response as below. Also, I want the fields to be in same order as below:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "group-1"
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "abc@gmail",
      "first_name": "myfirstname1",
      "last_name": "mylastname1"    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "xyz@gmail",
      "first_name": "myfirstname2",
      "last_name": "mylastname2"
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: can you give an example json you want to get from rest function

Comment: @SelimYılmaz I have added the response above in my original query.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all data by using `values` 
In your `Purchases` model change `vendor_id` line like this;

```
vendor_id = models.ForeignKey('Vendor', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='vendor_purchases')
```

And then you can get all data like this; NOTE if you do not use `prefetch_related` in for loop it access database for each user but now for all data it access database only 3 times

```
vendor = Vendor.objects.get(pk=vendor_id).prefetch_related(vendor_purchases).prefetch_related(vendor_purchases__user)

user_list = []

for purchase in vendor.vendor_purchases.all():
    purchase_user = {}
    purchase_user["id"] = purchase.user.pk
    purchase_user["email"] = purchase.user.email
    purchase_user["first_name"] = purchase.user.first_name
    purchase_user["last_name"] = purchase.user.last_name
    user_list.append(purchase_user)

result={}
result["id"] = vendor.pk
result["name"] = vendor.name
result["users"] = user_list
```